# Should I remove features that occur very rarely to build a model?

Tags: feature-selection, preprocessing, naive-bayes-classifier, nlp

I am trying ML techniques in language processing.
I have got 3000 short texts and I extract features(words and phrases) from all of them and build a vocabulary. I end up with 6000 od features and most of them occurs once or twice.
So for example from texts:

> 0: One text here
>
> 1: Another text there

I got

```
    One Another  Text  Here  There   Target
  0   1       0     1      1     0     True
  1   0       1     1      0     1    False
```

So if word "one" occured once I have got as a column and it is False for all other 2999 texts.
Should I drop these columns? Or should use different technique?
This amount of columns make me some problems becuase it takes a lot of time to build a classify.

Comment: Check out other NLP techniques which might help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

yes, if they occur so rarely, they can only lead to overfit, so it's better to ignore them as features.

**Longer answer:**

Usually one puts all those unique occurrence in a single feature/token, and that's the way I suggest you to proceed. So if you have two features that appears only once, you can join them to create a feature that appears twice.

But anyway, 3000 short text are too few to create a NLP model that can work well. 
To mitigate your lack of data, you can use pre-trained word embeddings like the ones available [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/). Doing so you can also keep most of the single occurring words/features, because in those word embeddings they already have a defined semantic meaning.

Comment: So can I just try to drop columns with different number of occuriencies until I will get the best accuracy? For example drop all that occured lest then twice, then ones that occured less then 4 times and so on untill I get best results? Or is it cheating?

Comment: Actually you are allowed to "cheat" as much as you can in order to get the best results, as far as you test your model on a set of unseen samples. So if you divide your samples in a training set (where you train the model), a validation set (where you check for the accuracy and tune the model parameters), and a test set (where you do the final check), and the accuracy on the test set is acceptable, then it's OK.

Comment: so is the validation set needed of I can just tune them and check the accuracy just on a test set?

Comment: Yes, what I call validation set is exactly what you need in order to tune your model